# How do you find the matrices of a representation given the matrices of subrepresentations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

Specifically, there is a passage in Dummit and Foote that says

> Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional $FG$-module and $V$ is reducible.  Let $U$ be a $G$-invariant subspace.  Form a basis of $V$ by taking a basis of $U$ and enlarging it to a basis of $V$.  Then for each $g \in G$ the matrix $\varphi(g)$, of $g$ acting on $V$ with respect to this basis is of the form
>
> $\varphi(g) = [[\varphi_1(g); \psi(g)][0; \varphi_2(g)]]$, where $\varphi_1 = \varphi\vert_U$ (with respect to the chosen basis of $U$) and $\varphi_2$ is the representation of $G$ on $V/U$  (and $\psi$ is not necessarily a homomorphism - $\psi(g)$ need not be a square matrix).  So reducible representations are those with a corresponding matrix representation whose matrices are in block upper triangular form.

How did they get that matrix?

Thanks!

($\varphi$ is the homomorphism from $G$ to $Aut(V)$, I'm not sure what $\psi$ is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all they're saying is that if $U$ is invariant, then the lower left-hand block of the matrix must be $0$, since elements of $U$ only have entries in the upper part in this basis, and this must be invariant under multiplication by the matrix. Then $\psi$ and $\phi_2$ are just new names for the remaining blocks. This only makes sense if the notation $[[A;B][C;D]]$ stands for the matrix

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
A&B\\
C&D
\end{array}
\right)\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you!  I think I need to review my linear algebra.